# Add css class onClick to idividual elements generated by mapping an array in React

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

```
<div className="sub-nav">
    <ul>
        {props.data.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <li key={index} className="sub-nav-item" >{item.name} </li>
            );
        })}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hi! I want to add an active class to an individual li when clicked, but I cannot seem to get it to work on mapped elements without adding it to all of them. This is part of a menu component in a React project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is hooks implementation.Incase you're using class I think you can derive from the same.

```
const [selectedItemIndex,setSelectedItemIndex] = useState(null);

     <div className="sub-nav">
                    <ul>
                        {props.data.map((item, index) => {
                            return (
                            <li key={index} onClick={()=>setSelectedItemIndex(index)} className={`sub-nav-item ${selectedItemIndex===index?'active':''}`} >{item.name} </li>
                            );
                        })}
                    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Since I am not aware of item object's structure, i used index. Otherwise I would prefer going for a unique value in item object. If name is unique then choose that instead of index.